# Get s3 files created after specified datetime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was wondering if there is a way that I could list object names from AWS `S3` bucket that are created after some specified date?

Comment: I do not think there is a built in option. Use `aws s3 ls` and process the output.

Comment: With what technology? Java? PHP? JavaScript? The CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's unfortunately no way to do that currently on the server side. Here are some related references which can help you write a filter on the client side though:

1. [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=65437)
2. [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1104)
3. [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-filter-files-in-an-S3-bucket-folder-in-AWS-based-on-date-using-boto)